# Jquery Not Loading ReactNative WebView In Android

Tags: android, jquery, react-native, android-webview

In my project i am using ReactNative WebView.My WebView Page Contain Lots of jquery Functions When i link That Page Only Designs are Displayed in Mobile, Functionalities are Not Working Properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you linked to the CDN of Jquery maybe? 
because you need to have it local and load it by this methode:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

and did you do this in your mainActivity.java?

```
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need to add `view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`   in mainActivity.java?

Comment: If you don't set that on true none of your jQuery or Javascript will be executed.

Comment: Ok. But i have a component called WebView in react-native. In WebView there is a property called javaScriptEnabled. I set a javaScriptEnabled={true} but i won't works for me.@Steven

Comment: How do you link to your JQuery in your HTML? Can show me your java code?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>`  this my HTML page link to JQuery. i was loaded JQuery in my local file itself.

Comment: Okey I find it strange can you show me your java code?

Comment: ya Thanks ...finally it works. added  `view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` .